# Derivative of matrix $\frac{\partial^2 \Pi}{\partial (A^{-1}X)^2}=A^T \frac{\partial ^2\Pi}{\partial X^2}A$, where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

I dont understand why  $\frac{\partial^2 \Pi}{\partial (A^{-1}X)^2}=A^T \frac{\partial ^2\Pi}{\partial X^2}A$, where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Can you fix the MathJAX so the equation appears correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyze the function in terms of the variables $w{\rm\;and\;}x$
$$\eqalign{
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
w &= A^T x \quad\; \qiq dw = A^T\,dx \\
\Pi &= \Pi(w) \quad\qiq
  g = \grad{\Pi}{w},\;\;P = \grad{g}{w} = \grad{^2\Pi}{w^2} \\
 &= \Pi(A^Tx) \qiq
  h = \grad{\Pi}{x},\;\;Q = \grad{h}{x} = \grad{^2\Pi}{x^2} \\
\\
d\Pi &= g:\c{dw} \qquad\qquad\qquad \{ {\rm differential\;of\;}\Pi \} \\
  &= g:\c{A^Tdx} \\
  &= Ag:dx \\
\grad{\Pi}{x} &= Ag \;\equiv\; h \\
\\
dh &= A\:\c{dg} \\
  &= A\c{P\;dw} \\
  &= AP\:A^Tdx \\
\grad{h}{x} &= APA^T \;\equiv\; Q
 \qquad\quad \{ {\rm desired\;relationship} \} \\
\\
}$$

---

In the preceding, a colon denotes the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$

Comment: How nice you are. Thank you so much. Perfect answer.